# How to reuse pseudo class in less?

Tags: less

Is there a way to reuse the pseudo class in less?

For Example:

This class already exists in some external file which I cannot modify.

```
.cssClass:before{
}
```

Now, I would like to make use of that pseudo class in my current code. Is it possible?

For example:

```
.lessClass{
    .cssClass:before; //but this is giving error
}
```

Comment: Try importing as `(less)`.

Comment: @Harry - I updated my comment. Please check

Comment: You are importing it as `(less)` and still it gives error?

Comment: Yeah. I am able to access class from less file. But, its not the issue. Issue is I am unable to use the pseudo selector class as shown. I have a class in ".fa-chevron-circle-up:before" in font-awesome.min.css. But, I am unable to use it in my less file as it is a pseudo class

Comment: Re-using the ruleset of a pseudo-element/class like that will not work even within the same file. You would have to either use `extend` or redefine the structure.

Comment: How can I make use of extend in my case as the existing one is a pseudo class? I cant use even like below
.fa-chevron-circle-up{
 &:before:extend(.fa-chevron-circle-up:before) {

 }
}

Comment: Just do it like `.lessClass { &:extend(.cssClass all); }` or as `.lessClass:before { &:extend(.cssClass:before); }`. I haven't able to test it but both should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62102/discussion-between-kalyan-and-harry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Less you can not mixin pseudo classes, see also [Allow for pseudo-classes to be used as mixins](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1630).

Probably  you can use `extend` to solve your problem as already suggested by @Harry.

```
.cssClass:before {
content: "test";
}
.lessClass:extend(.cssClass:before){}
```

The preceding Less code will compile into the following CSS code:

```
.cssClass:before,
.lessClass {
  content: "test";
}
```

or use: `.lessClass:before:extend(.cssClass:before){}` that will compile into:

```
.cssClass:before,
.lessClass:before {
  content: "test";
}
```